# Laravel and getting a list of all hasMany

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have:

```
class Project extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'projects';

    public function engagements()
    {
        /**
         * belonngsToMany is a strange name, but it seems
         * to be the only way of tying the relationship up
         */
        return $this->hasMany('Engagement');
    }
}
```

and

```
class Engagement extends Eloquent
{
    protected $table = 'engagements';

    public function projects()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
    }
}
```

I want to get a list of engagements by the project id... how does this work?

```
    $unit = Project::where('id', $projectID)->with( 'engagements')
```

fails:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'engagements.project_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `engagements` where `engagements`.`project_id` in (9))
```

**Context:**

- An engagement can belong to many projects.
- A project has engagements tied to it.

**Table structure:**

projects:

```
        Schema::create( 'projects', function( $table )
        {
            $table->increments( 'id' );    
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->string( 'title', 255 );                
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

engagements:

```
        Schema::create( 'engagements', function( $table )
        {
            $table->increments( 'id' );    
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

relationship:

```
        Schema::create( 'engagement_project', function( Blueprint $table )
        {            
            $table->increments( 'id' );

            $table->integer('engagement_id')->unsigned();
            $table->index( 'engagement_id' );

            $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
            $table->index( 'project_id' );

            $table->timestamps();
        });

        Schema::table( 'engagement_project', function( $table )
        {
            $table->foreign( 'engagement_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'engagements' );
            $table->foreign( 'project_id' )->references( 'id' )->on( 'projects' );
        });
```

Comment: post your table structures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both relationships should be `belongsToMany()`.

Additionally, it doesn't really matter, but you don't need an incrementing ID in `engagement_project` unless you plan on using it somewhere else.

To get your list, you would do...

```
$unit = Project::with( 'engagements')->find($projectID);
foreach($unit->engagements as $engagement) {
    echo $engagement->id;
}
```

Comment: Changing this over only brings back 1 result... but this issue may be further down in my code... I'll get back to you. :)

Comment: If it works and you are only getting one result, I'd check your database and be sure you have more than one record in both `engagements` and `engagement_project` for that `$projectID`